# Two different types of NodeLists? Cannot set properties on one NodeList to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, nodelist

These two examples are both node lists, but only the first works.

Works as expected:

```
var apple = document.getElementById('apple');
var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); // Line of concern

var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  array[i] = nodeList[i];
}

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Does not work (error is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined"):

```
var apple = document.getElementById('apple');
var nodeList = apple.parentNode.childNodes; // Line of concern

var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  array[i] = nodeList[i];
}

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

So if both variables "nodeList" are actual node lists, then why can't I set the properties on the latter example, nor anything similar.

Also, how do I solve the issue on the latter?

No jQuery please for this question.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **not** two different types of NodeLists.

```
apple.parentNode.childNodes
```

returns a NodeList, but it contains *ALL* the nodes--including new line & space characters between elements on the HTML.  So the reason I couldn't apply the properties I wanted was because some of the nodes were non-elements.

The answer then in place of that, is to use the element-only selecting methods; in this case: **parentElement** & **children**:

```
apple.parentElement.children
```

See [Mozilla's Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentElement) page on nodes, as well as the left-hand column for more node methods.